# Seeking a user-friendly AI photo editor

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a powerful yet user-friendly AI photo editor primarily for enhancing old photos and creating AI art.
The key features I'm looking for include:

1.Ability to enhance old photos, repair damage, and improve quality

2.AI art functionality to transform photos into artistic styles

3.User-friendly interface for easy and intuitive use

Please recommend software that meets these criteria, preferably for Windows. Thank you!